# Email me new responses to my posts. ERROR

Tags: support, stack-exchange, email-notification

I apologise if I am posting my question in a wrong place. If it is then kindly direct me about which sub-site this should be posted.

When I post any question on any Stack- Exchange site, I mark the check box at the bottom, which says "**Email me new responses to my posts**". But every time it gives an error "**the email address you entered is invalid**,".

[image]

- (1) If my email is invalid then how did I register with stack exchange.

  (2) If there is some 'special' place to write 'that' email address, then where is it ?

  (3) Is there any sort of tutorial / youtube video which helps one to get familiar with Stack Exchange itself, especially its interface ?

.

Answer (score 9):

For some reason when you registered your account, your email address was not inserted as the verified email for your account. It is currently empty, and we cannot send emails to you without an email set there.

The easy fix is to edit your profile, head to your [email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current), and enter in your email address there. It may or may not ask you to verify the email when clicking Save.

Comment: Still, error message can be greatly improved or at least link to something.

Comment: Possibly. This is just the same error message that would appear for an unregistered user that is typing in an email to post as a guest, rather than it being retrieved from their account. It's not special cased to catch a situation that isn't supposed to ever happen.

Comment: @sha Yes, saying that the email is "invalid" isn't the same thing as "the email is empty" or something like that.

Comment: @TechExpertWizard this, and also changing to something like "the email address associated to this account is invalid" would prevent lots of confusion.

Comment: @sha Yes, that's a good idea.